# Bash: Split a string into an array

Tags: arrays, bash, split

First of all, let me state that I am very new to Bash scripting. I have tried to look for solutions for my problem, but couldn't find any that worked for me.
Let's assume I want to use bash to parse a file that looks like the following:

```
variable1 = value1
variable2 = value2
```

I split the file line by line using the following code:

```
cat /path/to/my.file | while read line; do
    echo $line      
done
```

From the `$line` variable I want to create an array that I want to split using `=` as a delimiter, so that I will be able to get the variable names and values from the array like so:

```
$array[0] #variable1
$array[1] #value1
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set IFS to '=' in order to split the string on the = sign in your lines, i.e.:

```
cat file | while IFS='=' read key value; do
    ${array[0]}="$key"
    ${array[1]}="$value"
done
```

You may also be able to use the -a argument to specify an array to write into, i.e.:

```
cat file | while IFS='=' read -a array; do
    ...
done
```

bash version depending.

*Old completely wrong answer for posterity:*

Add the argument `-d =` to your `read` statement. Then you can do:

```
cat file | while read -d = key value; do
    $array[0]="$key"
    $array[1]="$value"
done
```

Comment: adding the -d argument gives me `read: Illegal option -d`, is the -d argument used for another command that i can use to do this?

Comment: Heh, actually got it wrong, -d should be the line terminator. The environment variable IFS controls splitting. Not sure why your read doesn't support -d.

Comment: Using `-d` with `read` is not POSIX compliant, unfortunately.

Comment: be aware that this `something | while IFS=... read variable ; do ... ; done` will redefine 'variable' only during the do ... done  loop, and outside of it it's left unchanged (why? because, in bash, almost everything after a `|` (pipe) is done in a subshell. And a subshell inherits global variables, but the calling shell doesn't inherit their new values and keep the old ones. Usually replace it with:  `while IFS='=' read key value; do ... ; done < /the/file`

Answer (score 3):

```
while IFS='=' read -r k v; do
   : # do something with $k and $v
done < file
```

IFS is the 'inner field separator', which tells bash to split the line on an '=' sign.